# How to create rounded corners in background of multiline text, where lines have different width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I need to make background color of text in EditText like in the picture.

Making corners rounded and paddings is quite easy with custom `LineBackgroundSpan`. I implemented it like this:

```
class RoundedCornersBackgroundSpan(val padding: Int,
                               val backgroundColor: Int) : LineBackgroundSpan {

val backgroundRect = Rect()

override fun drawBackground(c: Canvas, p: Paint, left: Int, right: Int, top: Int, baseline: Int, bottom: Int, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, lnum: Int) {
    if(text == null) return
    val textWidth = Math.round(p.measureText(text, start, end))
    val paintColor = p.color
    backgroundRect.set(left - padding,
            top - if(lnum == 0) { padding / 2 } else { - (padding / 2 ) },
            left + textWidth + padding,
            bottom + (padding / 2))
    p.color = backgroundColor
    c.drawRoundRect(RectF(backgroundRect), 3.fromDpToPixelsF(), 3.fromDpToPixelsF(), p)
    p.color = paintColor
}}
```

But how can I implement this "inner" corners, which annotated with arrows in the picture?
[image: picture with desired effect]

Comment: the answer is in different topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096722/rounded-background-text-like-instagram-replacementspan-not-working-as-required/49288455#49288455

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manage manually all possible scenarios, using different `EditText` for each text line, putting them in a vertical `LinearLayout` or in a `ListView`.

For the example image you posted something like this:

- for every line:

  - upper EditText length > this EditText length AND bottom EditText length > this EditText length ? apply background xxx
  - upper EditText length > this EditText length AND bottom EditText length < this EditText length ? apply background yyy
  - upper EditText length < this EditText length AND bottom EditText length > this EditText length ? apply background zzz
  - upper EditText length < this EditText length AND bottom EditText length < this EditText length ? apply background www

Obviously first and last line act a bit different.

Hope that helps and let me know if you find a better solution please

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find better solution. Seems that manually setting background is only possible way. But I'm trying to stay in custom spans "level" because manage many editTexts seems much more complicated. I post my solution soon, it almost completed, but it quite ugly, bloated and I dislike it.