# Rounded Background text like Instagram, ReplacementSpan not working as required

Tags: android, android-edittext, instagram, spannable

I was trying to do something similar to Instagram below -

[image: This is what i have done]

But i want this curves like Instagram -
[image: This is what i want]

Now i am stuck in one more problem - 
When i types,. text does not goes automatically to next line, I have to press return , like normally editText works in fixed width. (In short `multiline` is not working fine with `ReplacementSpan`)

Below is sample code for what i have done -

```
public class EditextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edittext;
    RoundedBackgroundSpan roundedBackgroundSpan;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editext_screen);
        edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
       // edittext.setText("Hello My name is Karandeep Atwal.\n\n Hii this is test");
        roundedBackgroundSpan= new RoundedBackgroundSpan(Color.RED,Color.WHITE);
        edittext.getText().setSpan(roundedBackgroundSpan, 0, edittext.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }


    public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

        private static final int CORNER_RADIUS = 15;
        private static final int PADDING_X = 10;

        private int   mBackgroundColor;
        private int   mTextColor;

        /**
         * @param backgroundColor background color
         * @param textColor text color
         */
        public RoundedBackgroundSpan(int backgroundColor, int textColor) {
            mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            mTextColor = textColor;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
            return (int) (PADDING_X + paint.measureText(text,start, end) + PADDING_X);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
            float width = paint.measureText(text,start, end);
            RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + width + 2 * PADDING_X, bottom);
            paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);
            paint.setColor(mTextColor);
            canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + PADDING_X, y, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v, Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {

        }
    }

}
```

Below is my xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="hi"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is what i am getting when i type using `setSpan` -

[image]

This is normal behaviour for fixed width, that i want -

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    tools:context="com.tttzof.demotext.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        int padding = dp(8);
        int radius = dp(5);

        final Object span = new BackgroundColorSpan(
                        Color.WHITE,
                        (float)padding,
                        (float) radius
        );

        editText.setShadowLayer(padding, 0f, 0f, 0);
        editText.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        });
    }

    private int dp(int value) {
        return (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * value + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

BackgroundColorSpan.java

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.text.style.LineBackgroundSpan;

public class BackgroundColorSpan implements LineBackgroundSpan {
    private float padding;
    private float radius;

    private RectF rect = new RectF();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Paint paintStroke = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float prevWidth = -1f;
    private float prevLeft = -1f;
    private float prevRight = -1f;
    private float prevBottom = -1f;
    private float prevTop = -1f;


    public BackgroundColorSpan(int backgroundColor,
                               float padding,
                               float radius) {
        this.padding = padding;
        this.radius = radius;

        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        //paintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        //paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paintStroke.setColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawBackground(
                    final Canvas c,
                    final Paint p,
                    final int left,
                    final int right,
                    final int top,
                    final int baseline,
                    final int bottom,
                    final CharSequence text,
                    final int start,
                    final int end,
                    final int lnum) {

        float width = p.measureText(text, start, end) + 2f * padding;
        float shift = (right - width) / 2f;

        rect.set(shift, top, right - shift, bottom);

        if (lnum == 0) {
            c.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
        } else {
            path.reset();
            float dr = width - prevWidth;
            float diff = -Math.signum(dr) * Math.min(2f * radius, Math.abs(dr/2f))/2f;
            path.moveTo(
                            prevLeft, prevBottom - radius
            );

            path.cubicTo(
                            prevLeft, prevBottom - radius,
                            prevLeft, rect.top,
                            prevLeft + diff, rect.top
            );
            path.lineTo(
                            rect.left - diff, rect.top
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            rect.left - diff, rect.top,
                            rect.left, rect.top,
                            rect.left, rect.top + radius
            );
            path.lineTo(
                            rect.left, rect.bottom - radius
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            rect.left, rect.bottom - radius,
                            rect.left, rect.bottom,
                            rect.left + radius, rect.bottom
            );
            path.lineTo(
                            rect.right - radius, rect.bottom
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            rect.right - radius, rect.bottom,
                            rect.right, rect.bottom,
                            rect.right, rect.bottom - radius
            );
            path.lineTo(
                            rect.right, rect.top + radius
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            rect.right, rect.top + radius,
                            rect.right, rect.top,
                            rect.right + diff, rect.top
            );
            path.lineTo(
                            prevRight - diff, rect.top
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            prevRight - diff, rect.top,
                            prevRight, rect.top,
                            prevRight, prevBottom - radius
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            prevRight, prevBottom - radius,
                            prevRight, prevBottom,
                            prevRight - radius, prevBottom

            );
            path.lineTo(
                            prevLeft + radius, prevBottom
            );
            path.cubicTo(
                            prevLeft + radius, prevBottom,
                            prevLeft, prevBottom,
                            prevLeft, rect.top - radius
            );
            c.drawPath(path, paintStroke);
        }

        prevWidth = width;
        prevLeft = rect.left;
        prevRight = rect.right;
        prevBottom = rect.bottom;
        prevTop = rect.top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are late @ttzof351 , i already did this by applying almost similar logic in `onDraw` method of `EditText`, I didn't use span. Well appreciate your work, Thanks for pasting code !!

Comment: Here is gist link to my custom editext https://gist.github.com/karanatwal/78085a546a309209a40892a595b4a476

Comment: @tttzof351 This code seems not to be working when you change the alignment of the text. It is always in Centered alignment. Any ideas how to update it?

Comment: @makiskontis I have modified `BacgroundColorSpan` to support alignment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295758/1529129).

Answer (score 6):

Enhancing `BackgroundColorSpan` by @tttzof351 to support alignment:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.text.style.LineBackgroundSpan
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.sign

class BackgroundColorSpan(backgroundColor: Int,
                          private val padding: Int,
                          private val radius: Int) : LineBackgroundSpan {
    private val rect = RectF()
    private val paint = Paint()
    private val paintStroke = Paint()
    private val path = Path()
    private var prevWidth = -1f
    private var prevLeft = -1f
    private var prevRight = -1f
    private var prevBottom = -1f
    private var prevTop = -1f

    private val ALIGN_CENTER = 0
    private val ALIGN_START = 1
    private val ALIGN_END = 2

    init {
        paint.color = backgroundColor
        paintStroke.color = backgroundColor
    }

    private var align = ALIGN_CENTER

    fun setAlignment(alignment: Int) {
        align = alignment
    }

    override fun drawBackground(
            c: Canvas,
            p: Paint,
            left: Int,
            right: Int,
            top: Int,
            baseline: Int,
            bottom: Int,
            text: CharSequence,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            lnum: Int) {


        val width = p.measureText(text, start, end) + 2f * padding
        val shiftLeft: Float
        val shiftRight: Float


        when (align) {
            ALIGN_START -> {
                shiftLeft = 0f - padding
                shiftRight = width + shiftLeft
            }

            ALIGN_END -> {
                shiftLeft = right - width + padding
                shiftRight = (right + padding).toFloat()
            }
            else -> {
                shiftLeft = (right - width) / 2
                shiftRight = right - shiftLeft
            }
        }

        rect.set(shiftLeft, top.toFloat(), shiftRight, bottom.toFloat())


        if (lnum == 0) {
            c.drawRoundRect(rect, radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        } else {
            path.reset()
            val difference = width - prevWidth
            val diff = -sign(difference) * (2f * radius).coerceAtMost(abs(difference / 2f)) / 2f
            path.moveTo(
                    prevLeft, prevBottom - radius
            )

            if (align != ALIGN_START) {
                path.cubicTo(//1
                        prevLeft, prevBottom - radius,
                        prevLeft, rect.top,
                        prevLeft + diff, rect.top
                )
            } else {
                path.lineTo(prevLeft, prevBottom + radius)
            }
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.left - diff, rect.top
            )
            path.cubicTo(//2
                    rect.left - diff, rect.top,
                    rect.left, rect.top,
                    rect.left, rect.top + radius
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.left, rect.bottom - radius
            )
            path.cubicTo(//3
                    rect.left, rect.bottom - radius,
                    rect.left, rect.bottom,
                    rect.left + radius, rect.bottom
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.right - radius, rect.bottom
            )
            path.cubicTo(//4
                    rect.right - radius, rect.bottom,
                    rect.right, rect.bottom,
                    rect.right, rect.bottom - radius
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.right, rect.top + radius
            )

            if (align != ALIGN_END) {
                path.cubicTo(//5
                        rect.right, rect.top + radius,
                        rect.right, rect.top,
                        rect.right + diff, rect.top
                )
                path.lineTo(
                        prevRight - diff, rect.top
                )
                path.cubicTo(//6
                        prevRight - diff, rect.top,
                        prevRight, rect.top,
                        prevRight, prevBottom - radius
                )

            } else {
                path.lineTo(prevRight, prevBottom - radius)
            }
            path.cubicTo(//7
                    prevRight, prevBottom - radius,
                    prevRight, prevBottom,
                    prevRight - radius, prevBottom
            )

            path.lineTo(
                    prevLeft + radius, prevBottom
            )

            path.cubicTo(//8
                    prevLeft + radius, prevBottom,
                    prevLeft, prevBottom,
                    prevLeft, rect.top - radius
            )
            c.drawPath(path, paintStroke)

        }
        prevWidth = width
        prevLeft = rect.left
        prevRight = rect.right
        prevBottom = rect.bottom
        prevTop = rect.top
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: If anyone else is struggling to get the background to show. Make sure you both setPadding and setShadowLayer with a radius equal to the padding on the textview that you apply the span to. If you do not actually set padding on the textview you can still get the background to show correctly if you also set android:clipChildren="false" in the parent view group

Comment: Hi , how will I call this class , pls tell, i need same .

Comment: @ShaluGupta check this answer for usage https://stackoverflow.com/a/49288455/1529129

Answer (score 1):

I implement new `RoundedBackgroundSpan.kt` class extends `LineBackgroundSpan`, becose it can draw decorate layer for text line-by-line.

```
class RoundedBackgroundSpan(
  backgroundColor: Int,
  private val padding: Float,
  private val radius: Float
) : LineBackgroundSpan {

  companion object {
    private const val NO_INIT = -1f
  }

  private val rect = RectF()
  private val paint = Paint().apply {
    color = backgroundColor
    isAntiAlias = true
  }
  private val path = Path()

  private var prevWidth = NO_INIT
  private var prevRight = NO_INIT

  override fun drawBackground(
    c: Canvas,
    p: Paint,
    left: Int,
    right: Int,
    top: Int,
    baseline: Int,
    bottom: Int,
    text: CharSequence,
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    lineNumber: Int
  ) {

    val actualWidth = p.measureText(text, start, end) + 2f * padding
    val widthDiff = abs(prevWidth - actualWidth)

    val width = if (lineNumber == 0) {
      actualWidth
    } else if ((actualWidth < prevWidth) && (widthDiff < 2f * radius)) {
      prevWidth
    } else if ((actualWidth > prevWidth) && (widthDiff < 2f * radius)) {
      actualWidth + (2f * radius - widthDiff)
    } else {
      actualWidth
    }

    val shiftLeft = 0f - padding
    val shiftRight = width + shiftLeft

    rect.set(shiftLeft, top.toFloat(), shiftRight, bottom.toFloat())

    c.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint)

    if (lineNumber > 0) {
      drawCornerType1(c, rect, radius)

      when {
        prevWidth < width -> drawCornerType2(c, rect, radius)
        prevWidth > width -> drawCornerType3(c, rect, radius)
        else              -> drawCornerType4(c, rect, radius)
      }
    }

    prevWidth = width
    prevRight = rect.right
  }

  private fun drawLeftCorner(c: Canvas, rect: RectF, radius: Float) {
    path.reset()
    path.moveTo(rect.left, rect.top + radius)
    path.lineTo(rect.left, rect.top - radius)
    path.lineTo(rect.left + radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(rect.left, rect.top + radius)

    c.drawPath(path, paint)
  }

  private fun drawTopCorner(c: Canvas, rect: RectF, radius: Float) {
    path.reset()
    path.moveTo(prevRight + radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(prevRight - radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(prevRight, rect.top - radius)
    path.cubicTo(
      prevRight, rect.top - radius,
      prevRight, rect.top,
      prevRight + radius, rect.top
    )

    c.drawPath(path, paint)
  }

  private fun drawBottomCorner(c: Canvas, rect: RectF, radius: Float) {
    path.reset()
    path.moveTo(rect.right + radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(rect.right - radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top + radius)
    path.cubicTo(
      rect.right, rect.top + radius,
      rect.right, rect.top,
      rect.right + radius, rect.top
    )

    c.drawPath(path, paint)
  }

  private fun drawRightCorner(c: Canvas, rect: RectF, radius: Float) {
    path.reset()
    path.moveTo(rect.right, rect.top - radius)
    path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top + radius)
    path.lineTo(rect.right - radius, rect.top)
    path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top - radius)

    c.drawPath(path, paint)
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
private fun initSpannableText() {
    val span = RoundedBackgroundSpan(
        backgroundColor = colors.random(),
        padding = dp(5),
        radius = dp(5)
    )

    with(spanText) {
        setShadowLayer(dp(10), 0f, 0f, 0) // it's important for padding working

        text = androidx.core.text.buildSpannedString { inSpans(span) { append(text.toString()) } }
    }
}
```

More details about implementation in this article:
https://medium.com/@Semper_Viventem/simple-implementation-of-rounded-background-for-text-in-android-60a7706c0419

Comment: Thank you! I've tried solutions from other answers, some of them don't support alignment, some have issues with path drawing like strange line gaps, but your solution works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modified @Rahul_Tiwari's version to automatically scale the padding and corner radius when the text size changes. It scales based on percent change from a default text size value. Plus setShadowLayer as needed. It also adds padding to the top and bottom of the text so the padding is equal on all sides.

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.text.style.LineBackgroundSpan
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.sign

class BackgroundColorSpan(private val tv: TextView,
                          backgroundColor: Int,
                          private val defaultTextSizePx: Float,
                          private val paddingToTextSizeRatio : Float = 0.125f,
                          gravityAlignment: Int = Gravity.CENTER) : LineBackgroundSpan {
    private val rect = RectF()
    private val paint = Paint()
    private val paintStroke = Paint()
    private val path = Path()
    private var prevWidth = -1f
    private var prevLeft = -1f
    private var prevRight = -1f
    private var prevBottom = -1f
    private var prevTop = -1f

    /***
     * Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
     * Gravity.LEFT
     * Gravity.RIGHT
     */
    private var gravityAlignment : Int

    init {
        tv.includeFontPadding = false
        paint.color = backgroundColor
        paintStroke.color = backgroundColor
        this.gravityAlignment = gravityAlignment and Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK
    }

    private val paddingForDefaultTextSize: Float get() =  defaultTextSizePx * paddingToTextSizeRatio

    private fun getTextScale(currentPaint: Paint) : Float  = currentPaint.textSize / defaultTextSizePx

    private fun getTagWidth(text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, paint: Paint, padding: Float): Float =
            padding + paint.measureText(text, start, end) + padding

    private fun updatePaddingAndShadowLayerRadius(padding: Float) {
        if (tv.shadowRadius != padding) {
            tv.setShadowLayer(padding/* radius */, 0.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), 0 /* transparent */)
        }
        val paddingI= padding.toInt()
        if (tv.paddingLeft != paddingI && tv.paddingRight != paddingI){
            tv.setPadding(paddingI, paddingI, paddingI, paddingI)
            tv.setLineSpacing(padding, 1.0f)
        }
    }

    override fun drawBackground(
            c: Canvas,
            p: Paint,
            left: Int,
            right: Int,
            top: Int,
            baseline: Int,
            bottom: Int,
            text: CharSequence,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            lnum: Int) {

        val paddingForTextSize = paddingForDefaultTextSize * getTextScale(p)
        updatePaddingAndShadowLayerRadius(paddingForTextSize)
        val width = getTagWidth(text, start, end, p, paddingForTextSize)
        val shiftLeft: Float
        val shiftRight: Float
        val fm = p.fontMetrics
        val tagBottom: Float = baseline + fm.descent + paddingForTextSize
        val topPadding = if (lnum == 0 ) paddingForTextSize else 0f
        val tagTop: Float = baseline + fm.ascent - topPadding

        val tagHeight = tagBottom - tagTop
        val radius = tagHeight / 10


        when (gravityAlignment) {
            Gravity.LEFT -> {
                shiftLeft = 0f - paddingForTextSize
                shiftRight = width + shiftLeft
            }

            Gravity.RIGHT -> {
                shiftLeft = right - width + paddingForTextSize
                shiftRight = (right + paddingForTextSize)
            }
            else -> {
                shiftLeft = (right - width) / 2
                shiftRight = right - shiftLeft
            }
        }

        rect.set(shiftLeft, tagTop, shiftRight, tagBottom)


        if (lnum == 0) {
            c.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint)
        } else {
            path.reset()
            val difference = width - prevWidth
            val diff = -sign(difference) * (2f * radius).coerceAtMost(abs(difference / 2f)) / 2f
            path.moveTo(
                    prevLeft, prevBottom - radius
            )

            if (gravityAlignment != Gravity.LEFT) {
                path.cubicTo(//1
                        prevLeft, prevBottom - radius,
                        prevLeft, rect.top,
                        prevLeft + diff, rect.top
                )
            } else {
                path.lineTo(prevLeft, prevBottom + radius)
            }
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.left - diff, rect.top
            )
            path.cubicTo(//2
                    rect.left - diff, rect.top,
                    rect.left, rect.top,
                    rect.left, rect.top + radius
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.left, rect.bottom - radius
            )
            path.cubicTo(//3
                    rect.left, rect.bottom - radius,
                    rect.left, rect.bottom,
                    rect.left + radius, rect.bottom
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.right - radius, rect.bottom
            )
            path.cubicTo(//4
                    rect.right - radius, rect.bottom,
                    rect.right, rect.bottom,
                    rect.right, rect.bottom - radius
            )
            path.lineTo(
                    rect.right, rect.top + radius
            )

            if (gravityAlignment != Gravity.RIGHT) {
                path.cubicTo(//5
                        rect.right, rect.top + radius,
                        rect.right, rect.top,
                        rect.right + diff, rect.top
                )
                path.lineTo(
                        prevRight - diff, rect.top
                )
                path.cubicTo(//6
                        prevRight - diff, rect.top,
                        prevRight, rect.top,
                        prevRight, prevBottom - radius
                )

            } else {
                path.lineTo(prevRight, prevBottom - radius)
            }
            path.cubicTo(//7
                    prevRight, prevBottom - radius,
                    prevRight, prevBottom,
                    prevRight - radius, prevBottom
            )

            path.lineTo(
                    prevLeft + radius, prevBottom
            )

            path.cubicTo(//8
                    prevLeft + radius, prevBottom,
                    prevLeft, prevBottom,
                    prevLeft, rect.top - radius
            )
            c.drawPath(path, paintStroke)

        }
        prevWidth = width
        prevLeft = rect.left
        prevRight = rect.right
        prevBottom = rect.bottom
        prevTop = rect.top
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this span is applied to a TextView (having uniform auto-size enabled), TextView starts shaking continuously sometimes. This happens because of floating-point variance of `padding` value in `updatePaddingAndShadowLayerRadius()`. You can fix it either by limiting padding changes to a minimum threshold or by making it static.

Comment: @rupinderjee Uniform auto-size would cause a feedback loop, so that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using a complicated path creation algorithm, you can use:

```
paint.pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(cornerRadius)
```

This replaces all sharp corners with rounded corners, with a specified radius.
Instead of `Span` you can create a `Drawable` and use it to set the `background`:

```
class ShapeBackgroundDrawable(
   private val shape: Path
) : ColorDrawable() {

   override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
       canvas.drawPath(shape, paint)
   }
}

textView.background = ShapeBackgroundDrawable(path)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNYBM.png)

We created a library that also supports Jetpack Compose: [library](https://github.com/exyte/ShapedBackgroundAndroid)

If you're interested in more details read the [article](https://exyte.com/blog/androidview-jetpack-compose-tutorial)